# attempting to make logging gui the first one to run from my application

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2, fxmlloader

The issue is, I cannot seem to find a way to actually put the Logging gui before my app starts, FXMLseveral any ways I can put in the loging form I made with labels and method which required login informations before my application pops up?

I tried two ways, first by calling :

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(
```

second one I created an :

```
AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResources())
```

third:

```
Parent root= (Parent)load.load();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] a Good Question. Then, read how to create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having. Once that's all done, just [edit] your question to provide the code you have so far, what steps you've taken to fix your issue, and clarify your question.

Comment: Did you try to use a Preloader? https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Login.fxml is placed inside the package called `com.example.login`, you can make it to be the first fxml opened by Javafx application by doing the following:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
      /*we make it the first fxml to be loaded. 
        Please note that you have to get the correct relative path to it or else 
        you will get 'location is required' error*/

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("/com/example/login/Login.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage visibleStage = new Stage();
        visibleStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        visibleStage.setTitle("My title");
        visibleStage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        visibleStage.setScene(scene);
        visibleStage.setOnHidden((e) -> {
            Platform.runLater(primaryStage::hide);
        });
        visibleStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> System.exit(0));
        visibleStage.sizeToScene();
        visibleStage.show();
    }
}
```

I would also advise that you add some code to your question if you really want a very helping answer, for example, your Application class code like the one that I have provided.